# Run-time error caused by wrong calling convention

Tags: visual-c++, runtime-error, calling-convention

I have the following class definition:

```
class IRenderable {
 public:

    virtual void Render( wxBitmap * ) = 0;
}

class MyClass : public wxWindow, public IRenderable {

public:

/* costructor, destructor etc... */


    void RenderBitmap( wxBitmap *bitmap )
    {
        // code
    }

}
```

where wxWindow and wxBitmap are classes belonging to wxWidgets library (a C++ portable library for writing GUI applications).

I am using Visual C. The following piece of code is wrong:

```
MyClass *c = new MyClass(...);
wxWindow *w = (wxWindow *)c;
IRenderable *r_page = (IRenderable *)w;
// bitmap is allocate somewhere else           
r_page->RenderBitmap( bitmap );
```

because i get a runtime error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

What's going on?

What i am doing is the following. A third-party library (wxAUI) get pointers to wxWindow in order to manage them. I have sublcassed wxWindow (MyClass) to add some specific code. So, instead of managing wxWindows objects i am using MyClass objects.
In some situations, i ask wxAUI to return me the wxWindow pointer of the "current" window, which should be a pointer to MyClass object. I want to call the RenderBitmap() method on those objects, so i need to cast it to IRenderable, but get that run-time error...

I do not have RTTI enable and don't now if this would solve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
IRenderable *r_page = (IRenderable *)w;
```

`w` doesn't point to an `IRenerable` instance. I can see why you'd think it does, but it doesn't.

Avoid inheriting from multiple classes, and google "diamond inheritance" and "virtual inheritance" for better understanding.

Extract from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) on the diamond problem:

> C++ by default follows each inheritance path separately, so a D object
>   would actually contain two separate A objects, and uses of A's members
>   have to be properly qualified. If the inheritance from A to B and the
>   inheritance from A to C are both marked "virtual" (for example, "class
>   B : virtual public A"), C++ takes special care to only create one A
>   object, and uses of A's members work correctly. If virtual inheritance
>   and nonvirtual inheritance are mixed, there is a single virtual A and
>   a nonvirtual A for each nonvirtual inheritance path to A. Please note
>   that nonvirtual derivation of A in this case will be useless as direct
>   access to any part of class A from class D will practically always end
>   up with compile error.